# Connection refused for localhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Hi Everyone so basically I have a small server running on a raspberry pi. I can access using :port but cannot access via simple python code using localhost:port or 127.0.0.1:port. Any ideas how can I find a solution to the problem.

Additional info

1.- Doing something like curl localhost:9000 gives ( note that doing the same with IP address it does not fail )

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000: Connection refused
```

2.- This is my etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   raspberrypi
```

3.- Running netstat -lnp

```
 netstat -lnp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 11.104.40.32:9000       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16229/python        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45539           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::53410                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -                   
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           -
```

4.- On my mac everything works fine. :P

Not sure if it help but real goal is to hit that small local server with python code 2.7

```
 response = requests.post( 'http://localhost:9000', data=data)
```

Comment: Why `11.104.40.32:9000` and not `0.0.0.0:9000`?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure why... can I change this value?.... Is it a raspberry thing or the local server? ...

Comment: Not a Pi expert, so unknown.  Likely the server setup.  Check the config files.  Have you considered: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: computer may have many network's cards (LAN, wifi, local loop) and every card has own IP. If server (program running on computer) uses only IP of WIFI (ie. 11.104.40.32) then local client can't access it using `localhost` - local client and remote client have to use 11.104.40.32. If server uses only `localhost` then local client can't access it using 11.104.40.32 - it has to use `localhost` (and remove clients can't access it at all). If server uses 0.0.0.0 then it uses all network cards in computer and local client can accessed it using `localhost` and  11.104.40.32 - remote need 11.104.40.32